# Angular6 .spect.ts Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for ElementRef:

Tags: angular

Estoy haciendo el test básico para mi componente, sólo necesito que pase los test de los imports, es decir, lo básico:

En  el componente tengo:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'pruebaTest ',
  templateUrl: 'pruebaTest.component.html'
})
export class pruebaTestComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('fai2') fa2input: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('fai3') fa3input: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('fai4') fa4input: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('fbi2') fb2input: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('fbi4') fb4input: ElementRef;
```

En el html tengo

```
  <input #fai1 #fa1="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="contractA" type="text" name="A1" class="form-custom--input" maxlength="4" minlength="4"
                (keyup)="nextInput(fa1)" required>
   <input #fai2 #fa2="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="contractB" type="text" name="A2" class="form-custom--input" maxlength="4" minlength="4"
                (keyup)="nextInput(fa2)" required>
   <input #fai3 #fa3="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="contractC" type="text" name="A3" class="form-custom--input" maxlength="3" minlength="3"
               (keyup)="nextInput(fa3)" required>
    <input #fai4 #fa4="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="contractD" type="text" name="A4" class="form-custom--input form-custom--input--last" maxlength="7"
                minlength="7" required>
```

Y en el test he hecho:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { pruebaTestComponent} from './pruebaTest.component';
import { ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';


describe('pruebaTestComponent', () => {
    let component: pruebaTestComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<pruebaTestComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [pruebaTestComponent],
            imports: [
            ],
            providers: [
                 ViewChild,
                ElementRef
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(pruebaTestComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should create', () => {
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (0.472 secs / 0.631 secs)
TOTAL: 1 FAILED, 1 SUCCESS

```
1) should create
     pruebaTestComponent
     Failed: Can't resolve all parameters for ElementRef: (?).
_reportError
_getDependenciesMetadata
_getTypeMetadata
_getInjectableTypeMetadata
getProviderMetadata
forEach@[native code]
_getProvidersMetadata
getNgModuleMetadata
_loadModules
_compileModuleAndAllComponents
compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync
compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync
compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync
compileComponents
compileComponents
invoke
onInvoke
onInvoke
invoke
runGuarded
runInTestZone
invoke
onInvoke
invoke
run
runInTestZone
execute
execute
invokeTask
runTask
drainMicroTaskQueue
invokeTask
invokeTask
globalZoneAwareCaptureCallback
     Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ElementRef: (?). (line 11364)
_reportError
_getDependenciesMetadata
_getTypeMetadata
_getInjectableTypeMetadata
getProviderMetadata
forEach@[native code]
_getProvidersMetadata
getNgModuleMetadata
_loadModules
_compileModuleAndAllComponents
compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync
compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync
compileModuleAndAllComponentsSync
_initIfNeeded
createComponent
createComponent
invoke
onInvoke
invoke
run
runInTestZone
     Expected undefined to be truthy.
invoke
onInvoke
invoke
run
runInTestZone


error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

He visto otros post y también he probado hacer esto ->

```
 class MockElementRef implements ElementRef {
        nativeElement = {};
      }
    providers: [
        ElementRef, { useValue: new MockElementRef() }
```

Pero sigo obteniendo el mismo error.

**EDITO:**

He añadido esto:
     schemas: [ NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA ]

El error ahora es:
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) ERROR

```
  {
    "message": "Error: Cannot find module 'tslib'\nat undefined:4:0",
    "str": "Error: Cannot find module 'tslib'\nat undefined:4:0"
  }
```

tslib es del archivo angular.json, ni siquiera es una dependencia del nodeMoules que pueda importar ...

Comment: Pero de nunca se tienen en cuenta las variables del component.ts con el del spect.s

Comment: Estaba entendiendo mal error... No sé por qué has añadido ElementRef, a la lista de providers: No es un servicio que tenga que ser inicializado previamente por Angular. Si lo quitas de esa lista debería funcionar.

Comment: Si lo quito sale un error de que no ha pasado el 'should create'

Comment: Pero ese es un error diciendo que al menos el test se ha completado

Comment: pero no lo pasa

Comment: @PabloLozano echa un ojo cuando puedas a la edicion del post

Comment: Mira a ver: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55326796/no-errors-schema-stops-karma-test-working-in-angular

Comment: Edu quita el ElemRef y el ViewChild de providers (ya que no son servicios) y coloca solo el Elemref en los imports. Si luego de esto te falla el "should create" te voy a pedir que envíes el componente.ts completo, de seguro falta algun declaration o import mas. Saludos!